# Issues with installing latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install it on a HP Pavilion 524g that is running Windoes XP right now, however it's just stuck at this purplish screen and hasn't asked me to do anything.  Could it be a disc error or just taking it's time?

Comment: Are you loading the 32 bit Ubuntu?  Do you know if your processor supports PAE?

Comment: 32 Bit. I do not know if it does.

Answer (score 0):

If your HP Pavilion 524g, Is composed of:

Pentium 4 comes with 300G hd, dvd writer/reader, cd writer/reader, floppy disk, 512Mb ram, 15' inch monitor, seperate speakers, keyboard & mouse. XP professional installed.

You should try: antiX

antiX is a fast, lightweight and easy to install linux live CD distribution based on Debian Testing for Intel-AMD x86 compatible systems.

antiX offers users the "antiX Magic" in an environment suitable for old computers. So don't throw away that old computer yet!

It should run on most computers, ranging from 64MB old PII 266 systems with pre-configured 128MB swap to the latest powerful boxes. 128MB RAM is recommended minimum for antiX. The installer needs minimum 2.2GB hard disk size.

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/antix-linux/MX-14.3-non-pae.iso

Comment: I'm assuming that it has original parts but I went into save mode and trying to install some drivers to alleviate blue screens if that be the cause of them.  Someone suggested for me to try Ubuntu because I couldn't get Win 7 to install.

Comment: Windows 7 with the ram will not run.

Comment: Yeah more than likely.  i probably won't install ubuntu since i've finally got it working better had to fix some system files.